# How to add validation in arrayForm?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I tried in this way to add validation to some dynamic inputs, but it has not worked, I would greatly appreciate your help.

This is the HTML where it defines the form with the dynamic inputs established in the ts, where if the input is not completed, the mat error should be activated indicating that the field is required.

HTML

```
<div formArrayName="dynamic_fields" >
  <div *ngFor="let field of dynamicFields; let i = index">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        [formControlName]="i"
        [type]="field.type"
        [placeholder]="field.name"
      />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-error *ngIf="i.hasError('required')">
      this field is required
    </mat-error>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the ts where I define the form initialization and put the validation so that all the previously defined fields are required.

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamicForm',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-form.component.scss'],
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {

  public dynamicFields: any;
  public form: FormGroup;
  public fields: any = [
    {
      name: 'name',
      type: 'text'
    },
    {
      name: 'atributte',
      type: 'text'
    },
    {
      name: 'grade',
      type: 'number'
    }
  ]

  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.start();
  }


  start() {

    this.form = this.fb.group({})

      this.dynamicFields = this.fields
      console.log(this.dynamicFields)
      if (this.dynamicFields) {
        this.form.addControl(
          'dynamic_fields',
          this.fb.array(
            this.dynamicFields?.map(x => {
              this.fb.control(x.name, Validators.required);
            }, {}) || []
          )
        );
      }

  }

}
```

Comment: why do you use a FormArray? **first** think the data you need: If you need an object use a FormGroup, if you need an array of string, numbers or dates use a FormArray of FormControls, is you need an array of objects use a FormArray of FormGroups

Answer (score 0):

Adding complete `formArray` to `addControl` method isn't working. You can do create `dynamic_fields` form array field before hand.

```
public form = this.fb.group({
  dynamic_fields: this.fb.array([]),
});
```

And then push each element of `dynamicFields` to `dynamic_fields` form array on at a time.

```
start() {
   this.dynamicFields = this.fields;
   if (this.dynamicFields) {
      const customFields = this.form.get('dynamic_fields') as FormArray;
      this.dynamicFields?.forEach((x: any) => {
        customFields.push(this.fb.control(x.name, [Validators.required]));
      }, {});
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="dynamic_fields">
    <div *ngFor="let field of dynamicFields; let i = index">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input
          matInput
          [formControlName]="i"
          [type]="field.type"
          [placeholder]="field.name"
        />
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get(['dynamic_fields', i])?.hasError('required')">
          this field is required
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Working Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k3xp2n)